# Enforce that all readonly variables are initialized in every constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, static-analysis, visual-studio-extensions

**Context:**
I sometimes end up in the scenario where i have a class that contains multiple readonly fields and multiple constructors. It can then be hard to remember to initialize every variable that needs to be initialized in the constructor. Resharper can warn if a field is never initialized but not if its only initialized by some constructor(s).

**Question:**
Is there anyway i can get IDE warnings or compilation errors for a constructor that doesn't initialize all readonly fields or get only auto-properties of a class?

Comment: you can create a [custom code inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html)

Comment: I tried this, but there doesn't seem to be possible to flag the absence of something. It only takes a pattern of present expressions and turns it into another pattern of present expressions.

Comment: I will usually ease the problem by having one constructor, possibly private, that will initialize the object properly. In this constructor I will have to make sure every field is catered for. The other constructors don't deal with the fields directly, but call this constructor.